# Ask where to store the file before saving a file as .pdf

Tags: vba, excel

I have the following code that enable to print a certain selection to a .pdf file.

```
Sub printIt()

        Dim input_value As String
        Dim file_name As String
        Dim Time As Date

        input_value = InputBox("Please state the name of the sheet")
        Time = TimeValue("9:20:01")
        MsgBox (Time)
        file_name = "C:\Users\Marc\Desktop\" + input_value + ".pdf"

        Worksheets("end_screen").PageSetup.PrintArea = "$B$2:$D$27"
        ActiveSheet.ExportAsFixedFormat Type:=xlTypePDF, Filename:= _
        file_name, Quality:=xlQualityStandard, _
        IncludeDocProperties:=True, IgnorePrintAreas:=False, OpenAfterPublish:= _
        True

End Sub
```

This all works fine. However, as I would also like to implement it on other computer I would like the function to ask where to save the file before saving it.

Could anybody tell me whether it's possible to change code below so it can pop a file screen so i decide where to save file?

Answer (score 0):

You need the `GetSaveAsFilename` method of the `Application` object. It will display a Save As dialog and return a string. You use it like this:

```
Option Explicit

Sub Test()

    Dim strOutFile As String

    strOutFile = Application.GetSaveAsFilename( _
                                InitialFileName:="export", _
                                FileFilter:="PDF Files (*.pdf), *.pdf", _
                                Title:="Save PDF as")

    'strOutFile will be False if user hit Escape etc
    If CBool(strOutFile) = False Then
        ' user exits
        Exit Sub
    Else
        ' do save
        '...
    End If

End Sub
```

In this example where the `'...` comment is - you would include your line for `ActiveSheet.ExportAsFixedFormat ...`

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
Sub printIt()

    Dim input_value As String
    Dim file_name As String
    Dim Time As Date

    input_value = InputBox("Please state the name of the sheet")
    Time = TimeValue("9:20:01")
    MsgBox (Time)
    file_name = "C:\Users\Marc\Desktop\" + input_value + ".pdf"

    myFile = Application.GetSaveAsFilename _
    (InitialFileName:=file_name, _
        FileFilter:="PDF Files (*.pdf), *.pdf", _
        Title:="Select Folder and FileName to save")

    Worksheets("end_screen").PageSetup.PrintArea = "$B$2:$D$27"
    ActiveSheet.ExportAsFixedFormat Type:=xlTypePDF, Filename:= _
    myFile, Quality:=xlQualityStandard, _
    IncludeDocProperties:=True, IgnorePrintAreas:=False, OpenAfterPublish:= _
    True

End Sub
```

Added one line in your code.

Answer (score 0):

Consider:

```
Sub printIt()

        Dim input_value As String
        Dim file_name As String
        Dim Time As Date, fldr As String

        input_value = InputBox("Please state the name of the sheet")
        Time = TimeValue("9:20:01")
        MsgBox (Time)
        fldr = GetFolder() & "\"
        file_name = fldr & input_value & ".pdf"

        Worksheets("end_screen").PageSetup.PrintArea = "$B$2:$D$27"
        ActiveSheet.ExportAsFixedFormat Type:=xlTypePDF, Filename:= _
        file_name, Quality:=xlQualityStandard, _
        IncludeDocProperties:=True, IgnorePrintAreas:=False, OpenAfterPublish:= _
        True

End Sub

Function GetFolder() As String
    Dim fldr As FileDialog
    Dim sItem As String
    Set fldr = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFolderPicker)
    With fldr
        .Title = "Select a Folder"
        .AllowMultiSelect = False
        .InitialFileName = Application.DefaultFilePath
        If .Show <> -1 Then GoTo NextCode
        sItem = .SelectedItems(1)
    End With
NextCode:
    GetFolder = sItem
    Set fldr = Nothing
End Function
```